# 404 on Nginx API location

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a simple web app, on an Ubuntu server, with a FastAPI backend (port 8000) and a VueJS frontend. I'm using Nginx to serve my content.
The front is well displayed, but the problem is that any request to the backend is ending with a 404...

My Nginx config is as follow:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/[mywebsite]/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name [mywebsite].com www.[mywebsite].com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass https://[mywebsite_ip]:8000/;
        }
}
```

`mywebsite` is my domain name and `mywebsite_ip` is the IP behind the domain name.

The backend runs with gunicorn (as a systemd service) and is listening at http://127.0.0.1:8000.
The frontend request the api with : `https://[subdomain].[mywebsite].com/api/` (which returns a 404). If I try to curl `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` it works well.

I tried to add an upstream in my nginx config (for the API part), to change the port, to change `www.[mywebsite].com` for `[subdomain].[mywebsite].com` in the nginx config, to request directly the IP (no DNS), but nothing worked...

Any idea what is wrong in my configuration please? Is the fact that I'm currently using a subdomain can be a problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are stripping out the `/api/` part of the request when you send it to `127.0.0.1:8000`. Try removing the trailing `/`, use: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;`

Comment: I tried the following `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` and restarted the service with `sudo systemctl reload nginx` but I still have the same 404 sadly